# set org startup folding in .dir-locals.el?

Tags: org-mode

I would like to have different start up folding in org mode for different directories. is this possible?

I have this in my .dir-locals.el

```
((org-mode . ((org-startup-folded . showeverything))))
```

It sets but has no effect when i open a file in that dir.

Comment: I think that's because buffer-local variables are set *after* the mode function has finished. The mode function (`org-mode` in this case) sets the initial visibility according to the global value and *then* buffer-local variables get their value, so setting `org-startup-folded` as a file local or dir local variable is ineffective. AFAICT, they are set after the mode hooks has run, so mode hook solutions are ineffective as well. Using an idle timer as in the answer below seems like the only possibility to me.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same behaviour ...

The following snippet helps.  I see a flicker even for very small files.

```lisp
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
      (defun my-org-mode-hook ()
        ;; Simulate C-u C-u TAB.
        ;; See (info "(org) Global and local cycling")
        (run-with-idle-timer 0 nil 'org-set-startup-visibility))
      t)
```

If the flicker bothers you, instead of installing the above hook, you can just do `C-u C-u TAB` after visiting the `org` file.

Comment: The answer here https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/72486/31220 supercedes this answer.  So, this answer can be converted to a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```lisp
(add-hook
 'org-mode-hook
 (defun my-org-mode-hook-vmnfgjk0eij0 ()
   (add-hook 'hack-local-variables-hook
             #'org-set-startup-visibility t t)))
```

This suggestion is based on [how `outline.el` handles `file-local-variables-alist`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/05297e40c0ab3ffcf5b5db74e4aa2aaefe05f5cf/lisp/outline.el#L366)

---

Btw, if you want to `showeverything`, do `M-x visible-mode`.